# Dig Command returning "SERVFAIL"

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, cname, dig

I am using aws to host my site and recently I created a new hosted and updated the name servers in the registrars, but when I use the dig command in terminal to see if the change has gone through it gives me the following error:

```
$dig wheybuddy.com
; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> wheybuddy.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 26614
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;wheybuddy.com.         IN  A

;; Query time: 203 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.1#53(192.168.1.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Mar 15 10:26:10 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 31
```

Any advice on how to resolve the error or even what the error means? I am completely lost.

Answer (score 3):

`SERVFAIL` means that the server couldn't answer the query at all. *Why* it couldn't do that is not possible to tell only from the response. In your case the name server giving the error message lives on an RFC1918 address, so I'm guessing that it is an internal resolver at your site. If you have the option, logging in on that machine and issuing the problematic query with `dig +trace` may help finding the actual problem.